# Heroku - how to pull data from database to the local database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to fetch database on Heroku and the data from there to save into my local database.

When I try

```
heroku db:pull
```

and confirm the name of the app, I get:

```
 !    db:push and db:pull have been removed and replaced with pg:push and pg:pull.
 !    For more information, please see:
 !      devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull
```

Ok, so:

```
pg:pull
```

returns:

```
-bash: pg:pull: command not found

heroku pg:pull
```

returns

```
 !    `pg:pull` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `db:pull` or `pg:psql`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

Thus, how to properly pull the data?

Comment: Have you find a solution to that?

Answer (score 7):

Per the [Heroku Postgres help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql), you have to specify the database you are pulling from and to for `pg:pull` to work.

```
$ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

This command will create a new local database named `mylocaldb` and then pull data from the database at `DATABASE_URL` from the app `sushi`. To prevent accidental data overwrites and loss, the local database must not exist. You will be prompted to drop an already existing local database before proceeding.

This also assumes you have Postgres on your local machine.

`heroku pg:info` will give you all available information, such as name, on your Heroku databases.

Comment: mylocaldb can be a Postgres URL like `postgres://postgres:p0stgres@localhost/heroku`, which will create a database called `heroku`

Answer (score 0):

in your project's dir, after installing taps gem, you can try using

```
taps server `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL` db db
```

to start a taps server, and then

```
taps push mysql://[usernme]:[password]@[host]/[database] http://db:db@localhost:500
```

to sync local db to heroku through taps