# `pg:pull` is not a heroku command, but `db:pull` is

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I've been trying to pull a database from Heroku.  For some reason when I try

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RAINBOW_URL newlocaldb --app myapp
```

it returns

> !    `pg:pull` is not a heroku command.  !    Perhaps you meant
>
> `db:pull`, `pg:kill` or `pg:psql`.  !    See `heroku help` for a list
>   of available commands.

On the other hand, the command

```
heroku db:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RAINBOW_URL newlocaldb --app myapp
```

is recognized, despite that `db:pull` was replaced by `pg:pull` according to e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406577/heroku-how-to-pull-data-from-database-to-the-local-database).

When I try `heroku help`, it shows an entry for `db:pull` but not for `pg:pull`.

So, it would be nice to use the command `pg:pull`.  But it doesn't work for me just now.  (I believe it did fairly recently.)  What could be the problem?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Edited to include an explicit question.

Comment: What version of Heroku are you using?

Comment: that was the problem! somehow it turned out to be the ruby gem version, which [has been replaced by heroku-toolbelt](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/10/15/upgrading-to-the-heroku-toolbelt). so the fix was just `gem uninstall heroku` and then `brew install heroku-toolbelt`.